# What's the connection between Tu B'Shevat and (Bukser) carob?

Tags: minhag, fruits, tu-bishvat

Tu B'Shevat many people eat many different types of fruit. Growing up and continuing until today there seems to be a Minhag to specifically eat (bukser) carob. Is there some sort of special connection between carob and Tu B'Shevat?

Comment: It's got a loooong shelf life.

Comment: ...and hence can travel to Europe from Israel by boat.

Comment: I was told that in Poland before the war, a Pineapple was the prized fruit to get for Tu b'Shvat -- and that it cost an average person a week's salary (to those who could afford it).

Comment: @Curiouser but pineapples grow on bushes, not trees.

Comment: Offhand, I just think it's to accommodate eating a new fruit so one can say "shehechiyanu". Although, I have no idea why there is any requirement or minhag to eat new fruits at all on Tu B'Shevat. And, why not give preference to one of the 7 species (how often do U.S. people eat pomegranates or figs, etc.) There is a somewhat well-known story about Choni the circle-maker and the carob tree. (See summary at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honi_ha-M'agel.) Maybe this has some connection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this link to chabad who explains this well.
 http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1109802/jewish/Why-Eat-Carob-on-Tu-BShevat.htm

There are more reasons,but have to find them.

Comment: +1. ["Even more helpful would be to also **summarize**, *in your own words*, what the external material says."](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/76)